# Sencha Touch Windows 8 App Images missing

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, sencha-touch

Am facing an issue while building the app in sencha touch for windows 8 platform.

Am successfully able to build the app ,but the issue is few of the images are not coming into the app. For instance under **app.scss** , we have specified the path for two images :

```
.submitPanel {
    background-image: url("../../SubmitButton-Off.png") !important;
    background-size: 100% 100% !important;
    margin-top: -1.8em;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
}

.submitPanel:active {
    background-image: url("../../SubmitBtn-On.png") !important;
    background-size: 100% 100% !important;
    margin-top: -1.8em;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
}
```

But first image is coming under build path of win8 app **({root}\phonegap\platforms\wp8\www)**, not the other one. Same is happening with few other files as well. (Note: All files are of png format,size between 4-12 kb)

Not sure what is the issue.

"../../SubmitBtn-On.png" is pointing to the root folder of sencha project.
I have placed all the images inside root folder.

can anybody help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place all the images under **'{root}\resources\images'** ,it worked for me.

Have tried the same path for images while developing the android application,but there on building the apk images were not shown.

May be windows 8 app development with sencha ,strictly follow this part.

Hope it helps!!